# How do I unzip .zip files in multiple directories?

Tags: bash, zip, unzip

My directory looks like this

```
./Dir1/Some file.zip
./Dir2/Some other file.zip
./UnzipFiles.sh
```

I want to loop through each directory in `./` and unzip each one's zip file.

`UnzipFiles.sh` looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in ./*/*.zip
do
        cd "$i";
        unzip "$i";
done
```

But that unzips everything into `./`. I want each .zip file's contents to unzip into the directory containing it.

How do I do this in bash?

Comment: if you add `echo "#dbg:i=$i" `into your `for` loop and comment out the other code, you'll see your problem. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter That showed me that `"$i"` was actually the `.zip` file, not the directory. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was `cd`-ing into each `.zip` file itself. Instead, I needed to do this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in ./*/
do
        cd "$i";
        unzip *.zip;
        cd ../;
done
```

Answer (score 2):

One-liner:

```
for file in `ls *.zip`; do unzip $file -d `echo $file | cut -d . -f 1`; done
```

Answer (score 1):

`unzip '*.zip'`

This will unzip every .zip file in the current directory.