# How to uzip a multiple zip files to some temp folders in bash?

Tags: bash, loops, zip

I am trying unzip multiple zip files in linux, but on not sure why this files are duplicated?

Input:

```
    #!/bin/bash
array1=(
    ${COMMON}/zip/folder1/
    ${COMMON}/zip/folder2/
    ${COMMON}/zip/folder3/
    ${COMMON}/zip/folder4/
    ${COMMON}/zip/folder5/
    ${COMMON}/zip/folder6/
)
array2=(
    ${COMMON}/my_source/file1.zip 
    ${COMMON}/my_source/file2.zip  
    ${COMMON}/my_source/file3.zip  
    ${COMMON}/my_source/file4.zip  
    ${COMMON}/my_source/file5.zip
    ${COMMON}/my_source/file6.zip
)
n=${#array1[@]}
for ((i = 0; i < n; i++)) do
    mkdir -p "${array1[i]}"
    unzip "${array2[i]}" -d "${array1[i]}"
done
```

Output:
I have unpacked files in folders from array1 and additonal subfoler var with duplicated files from unpacked zip.

Why I have 2 copy the same zip files?

A target is unzip files from array2 to specyfic folders from array1 without duplicate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I unzip .zip files in multiple directories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36190939/how-do-i-unzip-zip-files-in-multiple-directories)

Comment: your script is correct.. what do you mean with duplicated files??

Comment: it means that in folders from array1 (target to unpack files) I see 2 folders with the same content. One is expected with unpacked files from zip and second is folder include duplicated result from zip but there is also created subfolders tree ${COMMON}

Comment: It might not be relevant but you should double quote `${COMMON}` => `"$COMMON"`